# Regular Expression to check if part of a string is greater than a specific number

Tags: regex

I have a string of type `"CCUV2-20151223.1.122"`, this string contains three parts separated by a dot (`.`)

Is there a way to check if the *third part* (say `122` in this example) is a number *greater than a specific number* (say `90`) using regular expression?

Comment: regex cannot do maths

Comment: Thanks @vks. Just want to make sure if it is possible.

Comment: Well, a .NET regex can check if a number is greater or less than another number, but the pattern is really incomprehensible, and you really do not want to use that. Just extract, parse, and use regular number comparison methods.

Comment: To take the counterpart of comments, you can always craft a specific regex able to match numbers above yours, but's that's far from funny and without knowing in which language it's hard to give an example. [Example of why it's bad, testing above 82](https://regex101.com/r/yK1sS2/1)

Comment: @vks, regex cannot do maths but.... checking if a string represents a number greater than let's say... `90` is possible.  just try `/[0-9]*(9[1-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$/`  You can check a lot of number properties with regex, for example multiple of some arbitrary number, being less, greater, and much more.  Remember that you have only to write the regex once, and apply it forever.  And it does with only one pass over the test string (so algorithm is `O(string_length)`)

Comment: @LuisColorado the problem is if tomorrow OP need find greater than 1024 you will have to change to regex....its not a one time job for me )

Comment: @vks, look at the response given by ndn, as it describes a general procedure valid for any (constant) number, independently of the integer resolution you can have in your machine.  Nobody says that checking this or that predicate results in a simple or complicated regex.  You assert that regex cannot do maths and that comment has nothing to do with the question.  What was asked was if it's possible to check, and it is, and your comment is completely out of scope.  All problems solvable with a limited amount of memory and a limited amount of input can be represented by a regexp.

Comment: @stribizhev, the regexp approach has two advantages over the solution of converting the string to a number and compare after: It works in one pass over the string (you need also one pass to get the number and some more computation to check the predicate) and it doesn't depend on the integer size of your machine.  You can test number of only one digit or numbers of billions of digits to be greater or lesser than some number (for comparison predicates this seems to be dumb, but it isn't if you try to check if some billion digit number is multiple of 65537, for example)  In this case regexp wins.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it is better to just take that part of the string and cast it to an actual number using whatever language you are using. However, here is a general algorithm:

Lets say you want to check if a string is greater than a number, which can be written as [image: all digits]. You just have to look at the following cases:

- `[1-9]\d{n,}` - the number has more than `n` digits and doesn't start with `0`
- `[`[image: d1+1]`-9]\d{n-1}` - the number starts with a digit, greater than [image: d1] and continues with `n-1` digits
- [image: d1]`[`[image: d2+1]`-9]\d{n-2}` - the number start with [image: d1], followed by a digit greater than [image: d2] and continues with `n-2` digits
- ...
- [image]`[`[image: dn+1]`-9]` - you have all but the last digit and the last digit is greater than [image: dn]

Now just use `|` to combine these cases.

---

Applying this for `122` we get:

```
[1-9]\d{3,}|[2-9]\d{2}|1[3-9]\d|12[3-9]
```